# Massive text file, NSString and Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, memory, text-files

I've scratched my head about this issue for a long, long time now, but I still haven't figured out a way to do this efficiently and without using too much memory at once (on iOS, where memory is very limited).

I essentially have very large plain text files (15MB on average), which I then need to parse and import to Core Data.

My current implementation is to have an Article entity on Core Data, that has a "many" relationship with a Page entity.

I am also using a slightly modified version of this line reader library: https://github.com/johnjohndoe/LineReader

Naturally, the more Page entities I create, the more memory overhead I create (on top of the actual NSString lines).

No matter how much I tweak the amount of lines per page, or the amount of characters per line, the memory usage goes absolutely crazy (~300MB+), while just importing the whole text file as a single string quickly peaks at ~180MB and finished in a matter of seconds, with the former taking a couple of minutes.

The line reader itself might be at fault here, since I am refreshing the pages in the managed context after they're done, which to my knowledge should release them from memory.

At any rate, does anyone have any notes, techniques or ideas on how I should go about implementing this? Ideally I'd like to have support for pages, since I need to be able to navigate the text anyway, and later loading the entire text to memory doesn't sound like much fun.

**Note**: The Article & Page entity method works fine after the import, but the importing itself is going way overboard with memory usage.

**EDIT:** For some reason, Core Data is also consuming ~300MB of memory when removing an Article entity from the context. Any ideas on why that might be happening, or how that could be remedied?

Comment: Use instruments to see what objects are taking all the memory and what created them. And what's taking all the time.

Comment: Although I haven't ran it through Instruments yet, I can see that after I add a Page to the current Article, then call save on the background MOC and refreshObject:page mergeObjects:NO, memory usage stays very low. However, nothing gets saved this ways. Then again saying mergeObjects:YES (or not having that line at all) causes memory to goes crazy.